# When Do Connected Apps Show Under "Connected Apps"

Tags: administration, connected-apps, mobilesdk

In each org there's a list of connected apps available under **Administration Setup -> Manage Apps -> Connected Apps** where the admin can control certain settings for those apps, specically around whether users can self authorize or need to use PIN codes:

[image: Screenshot of the connected apps list]

I've got a connected app where the Connected App Definition is in one org (as is usual, you define it once and get one consumer key that will allow the app to work with all orgs), but even when I connect to my developer org with it, it doesn't appear under the list of connected apps, so I can't change any of the settings.

It *does* show under "Connected Apps OAuth Usage" but that's of little help. Does anyone know what controls that list of apps and why I can't see or configure my app in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't done this, but [the online help](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_edit.htm&language=en_US) indicates that you have to package it from a DE org as a managed package.